# Wifi connection "limited"

Tags: wireless-networking

Sometimes my wifi just randomly stops working for sometimes 5 minutes, sometimes 2 hours. On my laptop I see that my wifi goes from "connected" to "limited". My laptop probably isn't the problem because when I check my phone I dont have wifi on my phone either. It probably isn't my router as well cause I bought a new router. (the wifi problem wasn't the reason why i bought a new router) I have this problem for like a month now and it gets really annoying. I tried to find the problem but no1 could find the solution. Can anybody tell me what's the problem?

Comment: use an open DNS and tell us the results please

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn What result? My internet is working now so I cant test anything now.

Comment: @loko - Do it when the problem happens then.  Without the information we would be just guessing which isn't productive.  Limited internet means your laptop has access to the Intranet connection ( i.e. it got the ip address from your router ) but its unable to communicate outside of your network.

Comment: @Ramhound Just got the problem again and tried the open DNS. Didn't work :S

Comment: What kind of Internet access do you have? Cable? DSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened to me once. It wasn't either the router or my laptop because it also affected other devices at home. The problem was the Modem. After several weeks I've put the complaint at the service company they answered me those modems (the ones of the same manufacture date) were defective and I should replaced it. After I've changed it and the problem has gone.

Comment: Thanks man I will call the company. Vote up because you gave a logical answer. I was thinking about this as well! EDIT: NVM cant vote up yet :P

Answer (score 1):

were you able to access the wifi admin panel when this happened? When it says connection is limited try to go to "192.168.1.1" and see if you can access the modem admin control.

If you can't access the page or if it doesn't load it means your wifi has the problem of dropping connection every couple of minutes.It's because your wifi is faulty, try to get it replaced.

I have a netgear wireless router and it drops internet connection and wifi like every 10 minutes, it's really annoying.

Answer (score 1):

The "Limited" status means that the connection to your network is there but the connection to the internet isn't. If you're got a new router and still getting the same issue, its most likely your upstream provider.

When the problem occurs run the commands below and screenshot/copy them. Send that to your provider, it will help give an idea where the issue is.

The traceroute will help show if the issue is from your router to their router (ADSL/fibre issue), or a router in between that is causing the same issue.

```
tracert -d 8.8.8.8
```

and

```
ping 8.8.8.8 -n 10
```

(Note: Its the last 4 lines of ping that's important, not the "Reply from...")

If both of these produce results (Ie ping works and tracert doesn't show asterisk's), its possible that your DNS server is not resolving queries. If that happens, look at setting some different DNS servers. Google offer public [DNS servers](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/)

Comment: Thanks man. I really appreciate it. Wish I could vote everyone up here